# How to specify address for Remote Desktop Connection using VBScript?

Tags: windows, vbscript, automation, remote-desktop

I want to inject an address into the "Remote Desktop Connection" prompt using a VBScript. I was specifically told that I must employ [Windows Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do that, but after reading the documentation I didn't find any thing that could be used for VBScript. How can I proceed?

PS: As pointed out by Helen and [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/a10c5093-7777-43dd-aebc-a93925e8caf4) there is currently no support for VBScript to access UI Automation API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't actually need GUI automation here. To specify the computer to connect to, simply launch [`mstsc`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907.aspx) with the `/v` command-line argument, for example:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "mstsc /v:computername"
```

Alternatively, if you have an [.rdp file](http://ls.df.vc/files/rdp/RDP_file_settings.htm) containing the computer name and the connection settings, you can launch this file using `mstsc`:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "mstsc E:\ComputerName.rdp"
```

If needed, you can generate an .rdp file on the fly, like this:

```
Dim oFSO, oShell, strFileName, strComputerName

strComputerName = "computername"
strFileName = "E:\ComputerName.rdp"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oStream = oFSO.CreateTextFile(strFileName, True)
oStream.WriteLine "full address:s:" + strComputerName
' TODO: Write other settings
oStream.Close

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "mstsc """ + strFileName + """"
```

---

*Reply to comment:*

> however what I want to achieve is not the task of RDP-ing but the actual injection itself (this may be generalized into different windows of different applications).

Windows Script Host provides the [`AppActivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) methods for GUI automation, but they aren't fool-proof.

I'd recommend using a GUI automation tool, for example, [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) (which is free). In AutoIt scripts, you can use the [`ControlSetText`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSetText.htm) function to change the text in input fields, for example:

```
Run("notepad.exe")
WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]")
ControlSetText("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", "Edit1", "Hello, world!")
```

You can also use AutoIt's AU3Recorder to [record](http://ins3cure.blogspot.ru/2009/09/controlor.html) user actions, so that you don't have to write scripts manually.

Comment: Thanks Helen, however what I want to achieve is not the task of RDP-ing but the actual injection itself (this may be generalized into different windows of different applications).

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot use a thirdparty tool like AutoIt. If [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsaccessibilityandautomation/thread/a10c5093-7777-43dd-aebc-a93925e8caf4) is correct, it might be the case that UI Automation API is not available to VBScript (which is what I want to achieve).

Comment: @Minh: That thread is correct. VBScript doesn't have access to the UI Automation API. You can use UIA from PowerShell though, as PowerShell is .NET-based.